# How Can I Fix This Helper Function in Kanboard to get specific data from a JSON API?

Tags: php, json, get

Kanboard allows helper functions, I have used this helper function in a template file to show the data.

I am trying to:

1. Get the live currency rate for each set currency code from the JSON API result of currencies (code/rate)
2. Show the last updated date - only need to show it once

#### The helper file:

```
<?php

namespace Kanboard\Plugin\CostControl\Helper;

use Kanboard\Core\Base;

class LiveRateHelper extends Base
{
    // https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/php-currency-api
    // https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/free

    /*****
        RESPONSE JSON EXAMPLE
        {
            "result": "success",
            "provider": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com",
            "documentation": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/free",
            "terms_of_use": "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
            "time_last_update_unix": 1680393752,
            "time_last_update_utc": "Sun, 02 Apr 2023 00:02:32 +0000",
            "time_next_update_unix": 1680481582,
            "time_next_update_utc": "Mon, 03 Apr 2023 00:26:22 +0000",
            "time_eol_unix": 0,
            "base_code": "GBP",
            "rates": {
              "GBP": 1,
              "AED": 4.536918,
              "AFN": 107.049854,
              "ZWL": 128.90737,
            }
        }
    *****/

    public static function getLiveRate($application_currency, $rate_currency)
    {
        // Fetching JSON
        //$req_url = 'https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD';
        $req_url = 'https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/'.$application_currency;
        $response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);

        // Continuing if we got a result
        if(false !== $response_json) {
            // Try/catch for json_decode operation
            try {
                // Decoding
                $response = json_decode($response_json);

                // Check for success
                if('success' === $response->result) {

                // YOUR APPLICATION CODE HERE, e.g.
                    // $base_price = 1; // Your price in USD
                    // $EUR_price = round(($base_price * $response->conversion_rates->EUR), 2);
                    // $live_rate = round(($base_price * $response->conversion_rates->$rate_currency), 2);

                    $last_updated = $response->time_last_update_utc;
                    $key == $rate_currency;
                    $base_currency = $application_currency;
                    foreach ($response->rates as $key => $value) {
                        $currency_rate = $key .' '. $value;
                    }

                    return $currency_rate;

                }

            }

            catch(Exception $e) {
            // Handle JSON parse error...
                return 'Error retrieving live rate';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Calling the helper in the template:

```
<div class="panel">
        <strong><?= t('Base Currency: %s', $application_currency) ?></strong>
    </div>

    <?php if (! empty($rates)): ?>
        <table class="table-striped">
            <tr class="">
                <th class="column-35"><?= t('Currency') ?></th>
                <th class=""><?= t('Rate') ?></th>
                <th class=""> Last Modified</th>
                <th class="">Live Daily Rate</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($rates as $rate): ?>
            <tr class="">
                <td class="">
                    <span class="currency-coins-icon"></span> <strong><?= $this->text->e($rate['currency']) ?></strong>
                </td>
                <td class="">
                    <?= n($rate['rate']) ?>
                </td>
                <td class="live-rate">
                    <?= $this->helper->liveRateHelper->getLiveRate($application_currency, $rate_currency = $this->text->e($rate['currency'])) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
    <?php endif ?>
```

#### RESULTS / ISSUES

- The `application_currency` variable works fine, it gives the rate based on the set base currency
- The `$last_updated = $response->time_last_update_utc` doesn't work, I dont know how to call it in the template - I could be missing something
- The currency code and value returned is always the last currency code (ZWL) and last rate value from the json for any saved Kanboard currency

  - The `<?= $this->text->e($rate['currency']) ?>` shows fine in the template but I dont think it passes the variable to the helper function variable `$rate_currency`, otherwise why do I always get the last currency code from the json?

Comment: _"The $last_updated = $response->time_last_update_utc doesn't work, I dont know how to call it in the template"_ - you can't currently access it in your template - because you are not returning it out of your method in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe how would I return it without coming up inside the `foreach` for every currency?

Comment: Make your function return an array or object, instead of a plain string - and put both the last updated time and the other data you want to display, in there under different keys/property names. Then you should be able to access them separately in your template. (But if you do `$this->helper->liveRateHelper->getLiveRate(...)` twice in your template, it will likely still execute the function twice. So you should probably store the result of this into a variable first.)

Comment: EDIT 1:  
`public static function getLiveRate($application_currency, $rate_currency, $last_updated = '')`

EDIT 2:  
`return array ($currency_rate, $last_updated);`

Does this look right?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to add `$last_updated = ''` to the method parameters? That value gets determined _inside_ the method, passing it in from the outside makes little sense here to begin with.

Comment: ok I will remove it, I thought the helper `$this->helper->liveRateHelper->getLiveRate(...)` would ask for it in the template that's why... ok i will remove it thanks

Comment: so now I could call it as `$this->helper->liveRateHelper->getLiveRate($last_updated)` ?

Comment: No, why? That would not make _any_ sense. Your method apparently needs the parameters `$application_currency` and `$rate_currency` to do its job, so _those_ are still what you need to pass in. What it _returns_ is an array now - so you need to pick one element out of that array in your template.